# How to Convert mysql relational join table data to json data using mysql query

Tags: mysql, json

I  have following three relational tables like Country , Stare, City. I want to get these in Json format from relational data table, when I am triggering below query city arrays are coming multiple times. I Want to get the combine JSON data  as below format.

```
select JSON_OBJECT('country_id',b.country_id, 'country_name', a.country_name, 'stateList',JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT('cityList',(select JSON_ARRAYAGG(x.city_name) FROM city x where x.city_id_mapping=b.state_id  group by x.state_id_mapping),'stateid',b.state_id,'state_name',b.state_name))) 
FROM State b,Country a , City c where a.country_id=b.state_id and b.state_id=c.city_id by a.country_Id order by a.country_Id;
```

## Country:

```
County_id       country_name        currency  
-----------------------------------------------------!

1                    India           Rs.
2                    USA             Doller
3                    NL              Euro
```

## State :

```
State id     Stare name          language         country_maping_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------!
1            Maharashtra          Marathi           1
2            WB                   Bengali           1
3            TN                   Tamil             1
4            New York             English           2
5            Washington           English           2
6            Amsterdam            Duch              3
```

## City:

```
City id               City Name               state id
---------------------------------------------------------!
1                        Mumbai                    1
2                        Thane                     1
3                        Nagpur                    1
4                        Kolkata                   2
5                        Asansol                   2
6                        Siliguri                  3
7                       Tacoma                     5
8                        Olmpia                    5
```

Want to get the combine data in JSON format as follows

```
[{
            countryId: "1", countryName: “India”,
            subgrouplist:
                [{
                    State_id: "1", State_name: " Maharashtra ", language  : " Marathi ",
                    city: ["Mumbai ", " Thane ", " Nagpur"]
                },
                {
                    State_id: "2", State_name: "WB", language  : "Bengali",
                    city: ["Kolkata", " Asansol", " Siliguri"]
                },]         
        },
    {
            countryId: "2", countryName: 'USA’,
            subgrouplist:
                [{
                    State_id: "1", State_name: " New York ", language  : “English",
                    city: []
                },
                {
                    State_id: "1", State_name: "Washington", language  : "English",
                    city: ["Tacoma”,”Olmpia "]
                },


]},
    {countryId: "1", countryName: 'NL',
            subgrouplist:
                [{
                   State_id:, State_name: , language  : ,
                    city: []
                }           
]},]
```

Comment: Don't use the MySQL JSON functions. Create an ordinary PHP array, then use `json_encode()` to convert the final result to JSON.

Comment: I am not using PHP but spring boot

Comment: and if we achieve this result programmatic than its taking lots of execution time ..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I assumed PHP.

Comment: Can you please pretty-format/beautify this query you have shared?

Comment: I am getting the output of this query but city array coming multiple times. could you please help to modify this query ?